# How to overwrite a html-element but keep the rest of a block?

Tags: php, twig, shopware

I am extending a twig-template where i want to replace the line

```html
<div class="container">
```

with

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
```

**Twig-template**

```html
{% block layout_main_navigation %}
    <div class="main-navigation"
         id="mainNavigation"
         data-flyout-menu="true">
        {% block layout_main_navigation_navbar %}
            <div class="container"> <!-- This line should be replaced -->
                {% block layout_main_navigation_menu %}
                    ...
                {% endblock %}
            ...
        {% endblock %}
        ...
{% endblock %}
```

I tried to overwrite the `layout_main_navigation` by copying everything and changing the class of the `div`. But i am not happy with that solution as i have to copy and overwrite a lot blocks.

How can i achieve replacing the class of the `div` and overwrite as less block as possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can override the block `layout_main_navigation_navbar`, add the `div` element with the desired class `container-fluid` and then include the original content of the block `layout_main_navigation_menu` using the [`parent()`](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/2.x/functions/parent.html) function:

```
{% block layout_main_navigation_navbar %}
    <div class="container-fluid">
        {% block layout_main_navigation_menu %}
            {{ parent() }}
        {% endblock %}
    </div>
{% endblock %}
```